# Is it possible to calculate the work function of a metal with basic lab equipment?

Tags: optics

I have been given a problem in physics, its to prove if a lump of metal we have been given is real gold or not. One way to to do it would be to work out its density, which is fairly easy, mass/volume. (It is not real gold by the way, we just have to show it).

But as this is the route that all the other groups are gonna go down, id like to do something more interesting, but im not sure if its possible with the equipment, which consists of, basic optics equipment like a ray table, lasers,(which would give us a known frequency of light), prisms, mirrors, rheostats, transistors, geiger counters, thermometers, diffraction gratings, and a few other things.

Maybe its also possible to measure some absorbtion(fraunhoffer) lines? 
Does any body have any ideas or know problems that I might come into?

Comment: You'd need a pretty decent vacuum to do the photo-electric effect experiment. Is that possible with your "basic lab equipment"?

Comment: @dmckee, this is not true! Hallwachs found the photoelectric effect (Zink) in air. You can't determine the velocity of the electrons in air, but the borderline light wavelength will be enough. The problem I see is that work funktion data are rather coarse, maybe some metals "overlap" with gold values.

Comment: @Georg: Hmm...I guess so. I didn't know that bit of history. We always did it in vacuum to get a good measure of the stopping potential. I assume you use a very short gap?

Comment: No, You just measure the current from the Zink electrode into air. I have seen that experiment in this form in school (early sixties). The experiments maybe were induced by Hertz's observation that voltage sparked over air gap between Zink spheres at lower voltages when illuminated by light. Hallwachs had been Hertz'assistant. Vacuum technology for photo cells was not ready at that time.

Comment: Addendum: Hallwachs did not measure the dependence on light wavelength, this was done later by Ph. Lenard (1902). At that time technology of vakuum tubes was just developing.

Comment: For a high-precision measurement, the gold electrode will have to be extremely clean, and the measurement will have to be done in a light-tight box to keep out stray short-wavelength light. I teach a student lab where we measure stopping voltage as a function of frequency (with the electrode inside a vacuum tube) and use the slope to determine h/e. The y-intercept would be the work function. The results of that lab are not high precision, about +-20%. It seems unlikely to me that one could do much better than that on the work function, with the electrode exposed to air.

Comment: I dont think we have a vaccum:-(, so does that mean determining the work function for gold is out of the question? It think it must do because a lot of what was just said was way over my head. Would I also be correct in saying that "to see the absorbtion lines of the metal I am investigating, I would have to burn it and view the light through a diffraction grating"? That would be a bit much for the these labs too I think.                            (thanks for the help people:-))

Comment: Is it possible to reflect a laser off the metal and observe the reflection through a diffraction grating??

Comment: Think about measuring resistivity. Think about measuring thermoelectric coefficient (by building a thermocouple with a known metal). By the way, is there a restriction against using methods from the field of chemistry or electrochemistry...that would be easier and more definitive than most physics methods, if you know what you're doing.